# RVM Ruby installation not successful

Tags: ruby, linux, terminal, rvm, autostart

I'm trying to install ruby using rvm on linux debian. This is my problem:

Ruby didn't work at all in the terminal (that is, it said: ruby:command not found.

Then I followed this thread [RVM ruby installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885437/rvm-ruby-installation-issue) and it worked. However, after I closed that terminal and opened a new one, it didn't work anymore.

Do I have to change something in the autostarts? Can someone please help me!!

Comment: Go to my ["About me"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) section. One good tutorial for Ruby installation is there. Check that out.

Comment: You can get help from RVM's creator, Wayne Seguin, and other experts at the [rvm channel of freenode Irc](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `~/.profile` file contains:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

and your `.bash_profile` file contains:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

if it have it and still don't work add this line to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
source ~/.profile
```

I'm assuming you are using bash as your shell. You may want to check it in your user preferences (depend on your distro).

Answer (score 1):

I assume the installation worked, what did not worked is you missed to use the installed ruby:

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.0
```

in your case it would print you a warning about not using login-shell - follow the instructions, they ae there to help you